# how to develop my own protocol

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

In order to experiment with a new routing algoritm I've been developing, I would like to implement my own communication protocol within the Restlet framework (e.g., to replace the standard HTTP). Could you tell me how to extend the framework in order to introduce a new protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register new helpers in the org.restlet.engine.Engine object that would match your new Protocol object when doing new Client("myProtocol") or new Server("myProtocol").

You should have a look at how the SIP protocol is supported for example.